# Ultrasonic module Water proof vs non-water proof types

Tags: sensor, ultrasound, distance, waterproof, hc-sr04

Ranging SR04 Ultrasonic modules are available as water proof and non-water types.
[image: Water proof type SR04]

[image: Non-water proof type SR04]

In the [water proof types SR04](https://www.jahankitshop.com/getattach.aspx?id=4635&Type=Product) modules there is only 1 sensor while in the [non-water proof types SR04](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/HCSR04.pdf) there are 2 sensors, 1 as transmitter 1 as receiver. How does the  single sensor SR04 water-proof modules work with single ultrasonic sensor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to measure distance with a single ultrasonic transducer.

First the the transducer is used to transmit an ultrasonic pulse, and then the same transducer is used to receive the echo thrown back from the objects in front of it.

The disadvantage of using a single transducer is, that it is very difficult (impossible) to detect objects that are close to the transducer.

The surface of the transducer is set in motion when transmitting the pulse, and it needs to settle before an echo can be detected.

The settling time can be significant depending on the transducer type. Typically 1500us, which is approximately 250mm in distance from the transducer.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the non-water proof module (dual US sensor) with a water-proof module (single US sensor) in a circuit? It looks like possible as both of them have same 2 interfacing pins "TRIG" and "ECHO". The voltage range and distance specs requirements are satisfied by both. Would I need to change anything in my MCU code if I change the module?